# How to use Twitter API json with java

Tags: java, json, api, twitter

I am trying to crawl twitter for tweets with a special #hashtag and from the returning json I only need id, date, userid, text of the tweet exported in a cvs.

my code looks like this.

```
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.json.*;

public class CrawlTweets {


    static String AccessToken = "xxx";
    static String AccessSecret = "xxx";
    static String ConsumerKey = "xxx";
    static String ConsumerSecret = "xxx";

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
                ConsumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret);

        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(AccessToken, AccessSecret);

HttpGet request = new     HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23Nutella&lang=en");
        consumer.sign(request);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);


        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

        String id = obj.get("id").toString();

        System.out.println(id);

    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["id"] not     found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:459)
    at CrawlTweets.main(CrawlTweets.java:41)
```

What is wrong with the code? How can I extract the mentioned information and put to a cvs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON response format isn't as flat as your `obj.get("id")` implies.

Check out the example response format https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets.

`obj.get("statuses")` will return you a JSON array. You'll need to iterate over the array in some way. For each element in the JSONArray will be able to pull out an `elementInArray.getString("id_str")`.

```
import org.json.*;

...

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("statuses");

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_str");
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're (probably) getting an error back from twitter - make sure it [responds OK](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) and that the json it sends to you is actually correct.

Comment: No, the response is totally fine. I guess the obj.get("id") is the problem... if I change it to obj.get("statuses").toString() it returns something but way too much. I only want the text, date and user. And I don't understand how to access this information.

Answer (score 0):

User Json Libraries like Jackson to parse the Response if you are getting the response right!